# Use array of checked boxes to add class to resulting links

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can see the site I am working on here: [zelda.wptoolkit.us](http://zelda.wptoolkit.us)

Basically, I have a form with checkboxes that lists a bunch of 'ingredients' which are actually WordPress post tags. Users will click the ingredients they want and then it will auto update the 'recipe' posts based on whether the recipes (posts) include these ingredient options (tags).

My question is, how do I store an array of 'checked' boxes, then use this array of post tag slugs to add a class to their corresponding link found in the recipe result card?

Here is a mock up of what I am trying to accomplish:
https://cloudup.com/cNfVNMzePpl

Comment: so if multiple check-boxes are checked then all will be highlighted in your posts (as you shown in second pic)

Comment: set up your initial script with classes you know you can find. then when whatever is clicked apply whatever actions to elements having that class..

Comment: As i see that you are getting html (rendering html) when any check-box is clicking. So at the time of sending html to ajax as response add active class to ingredients . it will be more easy

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.  I think that's what you're after.  Can't really test it but it should work

```
$(".wpas-checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var activeClass = 'active';

        $('.myCard a').each(function() {
            if(val == $(this).text().toLowerCase()) {

                $(this).addClass(activeClass');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, this is definitely heading in the right direction! I added your code but I cannot seem to get it to work.  The end result should be any ingredient that is checked off in the sidebar will have the 'active' class applied to its associated link found in 'Ingredients' in the result recipe card. Basically, I want the selected ingredients to be highlighted, while the remaining unselected ingredients are greyed out. I'll keep tweaking this code, if you see any obvious problems please point them out! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that checkbox val not equal a link text for example
**value="any-flower"** in checkbox but in link text is **"Any Flower"**.
So must select label text of any checkbox:

```
   var label_text = $('---checkboxSelector---').next().html();
```

and push to your **checkedAttr** variable

Then in complete function of ajax :

```
    $('.myCard a').each(function() {
         var a_text = $(this).text();
         for (var i = 0; i < checkedAttr.length; i++) {
              if(checkedAttr[i] == a_text ) {
                  $(this).addClass('activeClass');
              }
         }
    });
```

Comment: Hey! This looks great. As for 'and push to your checkedAttr variable, I added this under the var label_text, but I am not sure if it is working correctly: `var checkedAttr = [];
checkedAttr.push(label_text);` The idea is to get the html text by using `.next()` and `.html()` on the checkbox, I believe the selector would be `.wpas-checkbox` though I may be wrong. Then, store the value in `var label_text` and then push each checkbox label text to the checkedAttr array. After we have an array of strings, we would then compare each string in the array to the links found under `.myCard`. Right?

Comment: Yes exactly. I've tested this way to chrome console on your site and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Had to modify Saeeds code, but he is a gentleman and a scholar who I am indebted to now!

```
<script>
(function($) {

   var checkedAttr = [];
   $("input.wpas-checkbox[name='tax_post_tag[]']:checked").each(function(){
      checkedAttr.push($(this).val().replace(/-/g, " "));
   });

   console.log(checkedAttr);

   $('.myCard a').each(function() {
      var a_text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      for (var i = 0; i < checkedAttr.length; i++) {
       if(checkedAttr[i] == a_text ) {
         $(this).addClass('activeClass');
      }
   }
   console.log('a_text: ', a_text);
}); 
})( jQuery );
</script>
```